# PHP how to count the length of each word in the text file

Tags: php, string

i need some help. how to count the length of each word in the text file using PHP.

for example. there is the test.txt. and the contain is " hello everyone, i need some help."
how to output the text and then count the length of each word，like:

array

```
hello => 5
everyone => 8
i => 1
need  => 4
some => 4
help => 4
```

i just start to learn php. so please explain the detail about the code what you write.

many thanks

Comment: read file --> filter comma's, dots etc --> use explode($filteredfile, ' ')

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$text = file_get_contents('text.txt'); // $text = 'hello everyone, i need some help.';
$words = str_word_count($text, 1);
$wordsLength = array_map(
    function($word) { return mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8'); },
    $words
);

var_dump(array_combine($words, $wordsLength));
```

For more informations about str_word_count and its parameters see http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Basically, everything is well described on php.net. The function array_map walks through given array and applies given (eg. anonymous) function on every item in that array. The function array_combine creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values.

Comment: Pretty code you got there, it's just missing the 'how to read file' part. Other than that, nice job.

Comment: @Jordy thanks, I added file_get_contents to my answer

Answer (score 1):

this is working

```
 $stringFind="hello everyone, i need some help";

$file=file_get_contents("content.txt");/*put your file path */

$isPresent=strpos($file,$stringFind);
if($isPresent==true){
$countWord=explode(" ",$stringFind);
foreach($countWord as $val){
echo $val ." => ".strlen($val)."<br />";
}
}else{
echo "Not Found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to process the words' length later, try this:

```
// Get file contents
$text = file_get_contents('path/to/file.txt');  

// break text to array of words
$words = str_word_count($text, 1);

// display text
echo $text, '<br><br>';

// and every word with it's length
foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo $word, ' => ', mb_strlen($word), '<br>';
}
```

But be noticed, that `str_word_count()` function has many issues with UTF-8 string (f.e. Polish, Czech and similar characters). If you need those, then I suggest filtering out commas, dots and other non-word characters and using `explode()` to get `$words` array.